# Is it possible to change the Windows cursor scheme with the command prompt?

Tags: windows-8, cursor, command, prompt

I would like to know if it is possible to change the cursor scheme of Windows 8 with a command prompt. I want to have it run on start up, since I can't seem to figure out how to change it permanently. If there is any other way to change it permanently, please let me know. The problem I am having is that I cannot copy my custom cursor files to C:\Windows\Cursors, because it says I don't have permission even though I am the administrator of the computer, and the only user on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the file "C:\windows\cursors" file in explorer. Right click on it and go to properties. Then move to the security tab and the click on add button to add a your list to the permissions if you are not already on the list. Make sure it is your specific user name and not just the administrator group.